# Фразеологізм "курити фіміам"

Tags: фразеологізми, словосполучення

Виникло питання щодо фразеологізму "курити фіміам". Чи можна його вважати фразеологічним зрощенням чи це фразеологічна єдність?

Значення пояснюється як "облесливо звеличувати, вихваляти когось". Фіміам - це іншими словами ладан. Таким чином виокремити значення кожного елемента можливо, тобто це єдність, але ж загальне значення не має нічого спільного із значенням елементів, тоді це зрощення.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості вимагають, щоб запитання містило контекст. Окрім того, запитання, які не демонструють спроби автора самостійно відповісти на запитання, не заохочують інших до того, щоб надавати відповіді.
Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також
[«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).
Ви завжди можете виправити запитання, для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: Дуже дякую, вибачте, що так сталося. Мої власні дослідження мене лише плутають, тому їх і не додавала спершу

Comment: Все правильно, ваші дослідження — навіть неуспішні і навіть помилкові — створюють контекст, який значно покращує майбутні відповіді.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Згідно з [класифікацією](http://pidruchniki.com/1016031648103/dokumentoznavstvo/klasifikatsiya_frazeologizmiv) Шарля Баллі, цей фразеологізм однозначно належить до фразеологічних єдностей.

> Фразеологічні єдності — семантично неподільні фразеологічні одиниці, цілісне значення яких умотивоване значенням їх компонентів. Значення фразеологічної єдності виникає внаслідок узагальненого переносного значення вільного словосполучення. Це результат образного метафоричного переосмислення словосполучення. Як приклади можна навести такі фразеологічні єдності: *зробити з мухи слона* "перебільшити щось", *мілко плавати* "не мати достатніх здібностей, сил, знань для певної справи; погано розумітися на чомусь", *прикусити язика* "замовчати", *тримати камінь за пазухою* "приховувати ненависть до кого-небудь; готувати помсту", *гнути спину* "важко працювати", *плисти за течією* "пасивно підкорятися обставинам".
>
> Як бачимо, для фразеологічних єдностей характерна семантична двоплановість. В окремо взятих ізольованих від контексту таких зворотах не можна однозначно встановити їх семантику, бо такі словосполучення можуть уживатися як вільні у прямому значенні і як фразеологічні в переносному, тобто вони е омонімічними. Наприклад: *Стоматолог закінчив примірку і поклав зуби на полицю. Гроші вичерпались, і йому довелося на деякий час покласти зуби на полицю; Плисти за течією ріки значно легше, ніж проти течії. Він усе своє життя плив за течією, ніколи не чинив спротиву. Дівчина намилила голову, а потім змила її теплою водою. На зборах йому добре намилили голову.*

Сьогодні вираз *курити фіміам* може бути буквальним: у багатьох релігіях світу це актуальна церемонія. Але переносне значення маємо наведене вами. Отже, справа - за контекстом, може, це зовсім не фразеологізм.